# Translating "there exists an element that comes after all others"

Tags: logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

> Consider the predicate language with predicate symbol $<,$ where $x < y$ means that "$x$ is an object different from $y$ that comes before $y$", and $=$ is the usual equality symbol.
>
> Choose the first-order logic formulas that correctly translate the sentence:
>
> "There exists an element that comes after all others".
>
> A. $\exists x\, \forall y\, (y<x)$
>
> B. $\exists x\, \forall y\, (\neg(y<x) \to (y=x))$
>
> C. $\forall x\, \exists y\, (x<y)$
>
> D. $\exists x\, \forall y\, ((y<x) \vee (y=x))$

A to me says: "There exists an element $x$, for all $y$, $y$ comes before $x$" so an element comes after all others.

C to me says: "For all $x$, there exists a $y$, such that $x$ comes before $y$" so an element comes after all others.

So, surely both A and C should be correct but I am unsure if I am translating them into English correctly. I am stuck between A and C.

Comment: C ssys that for every element there is a greater one while you are saying that there is an element greater than all others. The two are not the same: think in terms of natural numbers.

Comment: How do you translate A and C into english? What are they saying exactly? Like for C how do you know it means for every element x and not for all elements x @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Sentence A does not say that there exists an element which comes after all *other* elements. It says that there exists an element which comes after *all* elements. This is never true in a partial order.

Comment: So you're saying A is wrong? @Pilcrow

Comment: @computerscienceisapain A is wrong because it means that even if y is equal to x we would have y<x, which means x<x- This is not possible because from x<x follows x is different to x. So A is the right direction but  not completely correct.

Comment: @computerscienceisapain Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Comment: can this question please be deleted @dxiv

Comment: @computerscienceisapain Defacing or deleting the question now would be rude towards other users who took the time to read it, comment or answer. It would also be against the rules of the site.

Comment: Do not vandalize this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > A. $\exists x\, \forall y\, (y<x)$
>
> A to me says: "There exists an element $x$, for all $y$, $y$ comes
> before $x$" so an element comes after all others.

Try to at least translate grammatically, so that the result is easier to parse and make sense of; here, the first comma ought to be replaced with "such that".

Or, simply, "some element is larger than all elements."

Some other natural translations:

- for some element $x,$ for each element $y,$ $y<x$
- there is some element $x$ such that each element $y$ is smaller than $x$
- for some element $x,$ each element $y$ is smaller than $x$

Notice from my first suggested translation that the quantified (bound) variables $x$ and $y$ do not actually need to feature in the sentence's semantics and are merely *placeholders*. As such, it is perfectly legitimate for them to point to the same object.

> > C. $\forall x\, \exists y\, (x<y)$
>
> C to me says: "For all $x$, there exists a $y$, such that $x$ comes
> before $y$" so an element comes after all others.

Nitpicking for the same reason as above: omit the second comma.

Or, simply, "every element is smaller than some element."

Does any of the above translations match the required "there exists an element that comes after all others"?

> > B. $\exists x\, \forall y\, (\neg(y<x) \to (y=x))$
> >
> > D. $\exists x\, \forall y\, ((y<x) \vee (y=x))$

The correct answer(s) is actually from options B and D.

Comment: Is it because you interpreted the question to be in the bounds of a fixed set?

Comment: B and D don't answer the question that they follow all others, more that the list has an end

Comment: @computerscienceisapain Option D says that some element, say, $J$ is such that, whichever element (either $J,$ or else, say, $Q;$ let's just refer to this pick as $p$) you pick, $J$ either equals or is bigger than $p.$

Comment: how is J equal to P? they are different objects @ryang

Comment: Read carefully my previous comment: $p$ (small letter) is the label for your your pick regardless of whether it happens to be $J$ (yes, the same $J$ that I started the sentence talking about) or $Q.$